# How to save multiple entity in one action related in Many to Many Relationship [Spring Boot 2, JPA, Hibernate, PostgreSQL]

Tags: java, spring, jpa, many-to-many, hibernate-mapping

i'm writing here to have some hind about the solution that make , in short the problem that I've faced is: I have two entity in bidirectional many to many relationship, for instance I've the following Post and Tag entities:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "posts")
public class Post {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    /*...*/

    @ManyToMany( cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH} )
    @JoinTable(name = "post_tag", 
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "post_id", referencedColumnName = "id"), 
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "tag_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("posts")
    private Set<Tag> tags = new HashSet<>();

}

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "tags")
public class Tag {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;    

    @NaturalId
    private String text;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "tags")//, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("tags")
    private Set<Post> posts = new HashSet<>();

}
```

My problem is that in a HTTP POST Action I get the data for the post and a Collection of tags related to it and I have to save all with the condition to not duplicate the tags entity if the "text" is already present in the database. Assuming we have a Map with the given data, the code is as follow below:

```
Post post = new Post();
String heading = (String) payload.get("heading");
String content = (String) payload.get("content");
post.setHeading(heading);
post.setContent(content);
Set<Tag> toSaveTags = new HashSet<Tag>();
List list = (List) payload.get("tags");
for (Object o : list) {
    Map map = (Map) o;
    String text = (String) map.get("text");
    Tag tag = new Tag();
    tag.setText(text);
    post.getTags().add(tag);
    tag.getPosts().add(post);
    log.info("post has {}# tag", post.getTags().size());
    toSaveTags.add(tag);
};
//method to save it all
postRepository.saveWithTags(post, toSaveTags);
```

My solution was to design a Repository class with the method shown above, as follow:

```
@Repository
public class PostTagsRepositoryImpl implements PostTagsRepository {

    @Autowired
    private EntityManagerFactory emf;

    @Override
    public Post saveWithTags(Post post, Collection<Tag> tags) {
        EntityManager entityManager = emf.createEntityManager();
        post.getTags().clear();
        for (Tag tag : tags) {

            tag.getPosts().clear();
            Tag searchedTag = null;
            try {
                searchedTag = entityManager.createQuery(
                        "select t "
                        + "from Tag t "
                        + "join fetch t.posts "
                        + "where t.text = :text", Tag.class)
                        .setParameter("text", tag.getText())
                        .getSingleResult();
            } catch (NoResultException e) {/* DO NOTHING */}
            if (searchedTag == null) {
                post.getTags().add(tag);
                tag.getPosts().add(post);
            } else {
                entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
                entityManager.detach(searchedTag);

                post.getTags().add(searchedTag);
                searchedTag.getPosts().add(post);
                entityManager.merge(searchedTag);
                entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
            }
        }

        entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
        entityManager.merge(post);
        entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
        return post;
    }

}
```

My questions are : Could I implement it better? maybe in a single query/transaction?  Could you give me some tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some points:

- you link both entities and then `clear` relations in the repository. As you don't have invariants between them first linkage is useless.
- > maybe in a single query/transaction?

Single query is not really possible but single transaction is indeed what you need to achieve to avoid inconsistency problems.

- Unfortunately cascading merge won't work with naturalid so you have to produce this behavior yourself.
  So for each tag verify if it exists:

```java
Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);

Tag t= session.bySimpleNaturalId(Tag.class).load(“some txt”);
```

Depending on the result you have to load into the `Post` object the existing tag one (already on db and recover via `bySimpleNaturalId`) or the new one. Then cascading merge on `Post` will do the rest.

- You always create new entity manager on each call to your repository. You should overcome this by injection the shared entitymanager directly.

```java
@Autowired
Private EntityManager em;
```

It is thread safe.

Comment: Thank you for your tips, I've injected the EntityManager as you suggest but it gives me a org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException, the message states: Not allowed to create transaction on shared EntityManager - use Spring transactions or EJB CMT instead;

Comment: Indeed you should not call `beginTransaction` on the shared entitymanager. Instead wrap your service or repository implementation with `@Transactional`... let me know if it works

Comment: By wrapping the service class with @Transactional how I gonna get the EntityManager instance in the method?

Comment: What you can do is wrap your service method with `@Transactional` and injection of shared EM (via Autowired annotation) in the repository will work without any problem. You don't have to begin/commit/rollback yourself....

Comment: Ok, it works! I wasn't aware of make use of @Transactional annotation.